# Disable border (border: 0 none)

Tags: css, border

I've always used the notation `border: 0 none`, presumably that means `border-width: 0` and `border-style: none`.

Does anybody else use write it this way? Is it really necessary to declare both style and width for safe removal?

Comment: I was always thinking that border: 0 is enough, or border: none. Never have problems and never was thinking about that.

Answer (score 6):

`border:none;` should achieve the same effect according to the spec.

The `border` property can be set with the following values:

```
<line-width> || <line-style> || <color>
```

When one of these values is omitted its value is set to its initial value.  So `border:none;` will actually have the initial `line-width` value added:

`border: medium none;`

However, the `line-style` value of `none` will cause the `color` and `width` values to be ignored as stated in the [CSS Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#border-style):

> ‘none’
>       No border. Color and width are ignored (i.e., the border has width 0).

Answer (score 2):

Just having `border: none;` or `border: 0;` is enough. You can find more information about the border shorthand [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border).